# Search tags forgotten

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-search

You are on the `Questions` tab and select a tag or used the search box. While switching tabs on the local nav has no issues, when you switch to the Unanswered tab on the global nav, the current search tags/terms are forgotten.

[image]

Why would someone want to do this when there's a local `Unanswered` section in Questions? Well, possibly to see the **Newest** or **No Answer** *Unanswered* questions. This can be quite aggravating when there are have 2+ tags, a search term, or you are looking for one of 2 tags (as this requires you manually put an `or` in the url)

**So I'd love for the site to remember your search tags when switching on the global nav.**

As far as I understand it, the reason this happens is you're switching to a totally different page, and also the other global tabs are not question searches. However, since when you arrive at these other pages your search is blank as well it would be cool that it just showed you related information for those tags (wouldn't be hard for badges and tag pages, and I guess it could show users who recently posted in questions related to the tags. Note: this is just an additional idea).

So is there a reason I'm missing this has not been done, or am I just **that** lazy?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you are lazy. I noticed exactly the same thing. this could be a good candidate to be proposed for edit. I think global nab should be remembered

Comment: I'm not only one! It's just one of those little things that (in theory?) wouldn't be terribly hard to implement either. It would make ease of access and flow from one section to another that much nicer :)